# regex matching multiple urls

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match multiple urls with request types:

for example, for endpoints:

```
GET:/shop/australia/sydney/admin
GET:/shop/australia/sydney/read
GET:/shop/australia/sydney/customer/1
PATCH:/shop/australia/sydney/customer/1
DEL:/shop/australia/sydney/customer/1
```

for a single url, this works fine:

```
(GET:\/shop\/australia\/sydney\/admin(\/)?
```

but i need a regex to match all the above ones. i tried something like:

```
(GET:\/shop\/australia\/sydney\/admin(\/)?|GET:\/shop\/australia\/sydney\/read(\/)?)
```

but it isn't really working for me.

Comment: You don't need to escape `/` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape `/` in Python regexp, since it's not a delimiter.

You don't need to put a group around a single character when quantifying it, so `(\/)?` can just be `/?`.

Try to find the common parts of the regexp so you don't have to keep repeating it in all the alternatives.

```
GET:/shop/australia/sydney/(?:admin|read)/?|(?:GET|PATCH|DEL):/shop/australia/sydney/customer/\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but bear in mind that it's very general and will capture other patterns as well:

```
[A-Z]*:(\/\w+)*(\/\d+)*
```

If you really want something more specific you can try something like this:

```
[A-Z]*:\/shop\/australia\/sydney\/\w+(\/\d+)*
```